# "my logins" error in profile page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, login

> [image]

When I go to my profile page(Stack Overflow), a click on "my logins", i have seen an error, but it just a dialog with red background, so what is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, i'm sorry, when i use 'Inspect element' in Chrome, Firewall drop that popup.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Dropped by firewall) 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/popup/logins/2057319
```